# how to generate dynamic SolrQueryByField

Tags: solr, solrnet

based on the checkboxes selected, I want to query fields in SolrNet.  I can have multiple checkboxes, for example, for field1, field2, field3, field4, etc..  so if the user selects field2 and field4, my solrquery is:

_solrquery = new SolrQueryByField("category", field2) || new SolrQueryByField("category", field4);

How do I create the above query dynamically depending upon the checkboxes selected which can be any combination?  So I want to be able to append for example new SolrQueryByField("category", fieldX) to the above query

Comment: [According to the source](https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet/blob/master/SolrNet/AbstractSolrQuery.cs) you can use the `|` operator, so `_solrquery = first query; _solrquery |= second query; _solrquery |= third query;` should work?

Comment: lets say as I am going through the checkboxes I find field 5,6 are also checked.  How do I append filed 5, field 6 to the existing query  _solrquery = new SolrQueryByField("category", field2) || new SolrQueryByField("category", field4), instead of rewriting the  whole query again as _solrquery = new SolrQueryByField("category", field2) || new SolrQueryByField("category", field4) || new SolrQueryByField("category", field5) || new SolrQueryByField("category", field6)

Comment: You can use `|=` to append another OR condition to the query. You could start with an invalid value and then OR all the other terms onto it.